# Maven not working after downgrading java version

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have recently downgraded my java on my mac from java 8 to java 7 to support the project am working on. Prior to this i have installed maven and it was working fine.
Now after i have downgraded, i am getting an error while trying to check the maven version using the command :
`mvn --version`

The Error :

```
Nitins-MacBook-Pro:~ nitinsuryavegi$ mvn --version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

How do i get it back to working fine. Please help. I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Did you set your MAVEN_HOME correctly?

Comment: You should update your JAVA_HOME path for maven, or you can reinstall mvn using home-brew "brew update" and "brew install maven"

Comment: You should set java_home using export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java> and try maven --version it should work

Comment: Why did you have to downgrade Java version? "to support the project am working on" - do you mean that you needed to code to Java 7? In which case all you needed to do was to change project compliance settings...

Comment: @chokdee: 
I have set :
`M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3`
`export M2_HOME`

`PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin`
`export PATH.`

Is it right ? Because i still dont see anything when i type `echo $MAVEN_HOME`. It a blank. 
But when i type `which mvn`- it shows me '/usr/local/bin/mvn'

Comment: @nileshvirkar: I have updated my JAVA_HOME path for maven. 
Using these set of statements: 
`M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3`
`export M2_HOME`

`PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin`
`export PATH.`

Am still not able to get it right.

I have aslo tried to reinstall maven by using `brew update` and then `brew install maven` and am getting - `Warning: maven-3.3.3 already installed`.

Comment: try to reinstall it using `brew reinstall maven`